# Daily Internet usage datasets

Tags: data-request, internet

I am looking for data that measures the density of internet usage (packet exchanges) throughout a day. Could be from anywhere in the world, from any time period, reflecting any range of devices, and output in any data format. [This](https://census2012.sourceforge.net/images/geovideo.gif) is a classic example.